# Read HTTPServletRequest's POST body AND then call getParameter in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, post, tomcat5.5

I am in the situation where my application needs to inspect the content/data/body/payload of a POST request without changing the results of subsequent getParameter calls.

**Reading the body from the inputStream:**

The body can be read using the InputStream from `request.getInputStream` or BufferedReader from `request.getReader`.

**Reading POST parameters:**

POST requests typically include request parameters in the body of the request. These can be retrieved using `getParameter`.

**The Problem:**

the first `getParameter` call internally parses the inputStream and inserts all parameters into a parameter HashMap.  It requires the inputStream to still contain the contents for parsing.  Thus one cannot inspect the content and still have a working getParameter call.

**Proposed (but not sufficient) Solution**

Create a request wrapper that caches the inputstream and returns the cache for getInputStream.

I've seen that solution suggested all over the web, but it doesn't work, because `getParameter` doesn't actually call `getInputStream`, but refers to the original inputBuffer buried in the request object.  I've tried it, both from within the Servlet and by using a filter

The only solution I can think of involves rewriting getParameter to actually parse the cached inputstream manually.  But this feels like a bad idea.

Does anybody have any alternative that works?  (This is Tomcat 5.5)  This feels like it should be a common use-case; I can't believe how difficult it is.

Comment: The answer to that question is not a solution. I've implemented it and it failed to fix the problem.  Since then I read the tomcat source and realised that getParameter does not call getInputStream, as I stated above, and so would not read from the cached version of the stream. 
see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/catalina/5.5.23/org/apache/catalina/connector/RequestFacade.java?av=f#342
 I'm not sure why people seem to have found it to be a solution.

Comment: The method `getParameter` call `getInputStream`. First, `getParameter`  call `parseParameters`, then `parseParameters` call `readPostBody`, then `readPostBody` call `getInputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @caskey, a possible solution would be to use reflection to replace the inputBuffer with a replayable inputbuffer.  But I did not use that approach as it felt naughty.

Instead I created a request wrapper in a filter which reads the inputstream into a byte array and returns a new `InputStream` that internally uses a `ByteArrayInputStream` around that array for all `getInputStream` calls.

After reading the inputstream to the byte array, I create a parameter map by parsing the payload.  I merged the superclass' parameter map in to support GET cases with query parameters.  I've overridden all the getParameter*() methods to use this parameter map.

I used `apache.axis.utils.IOUtils.readFully` to easily read the stream in to the byte array.  And I'm currently using `javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.parsePostData` to parse the data into parameter map. `HttpUtils.parsePostData` is actually deprecated, so I'll likely replace it with a better version when I find it.

But this works, yay!

Answer (score 1):

(That's a rather old tomcat, I'm assuming upgrading to a more modern one isn't an option.)

What you want to do will require intercepting the construction of the concrete HttpServletResponse object wrapping the underlying InputStream.  Wrapping that InputStream in a push-back input stream (or equivalent) is necessary.

Tomcat 5.5 is so old I can't even think how that would be accomplished 'normally', but perhaps you could write a filter that uses reflection to reach in and swap the InputStream object inside the concrete request object.

Comment: Yeah. You're pretty spot on with the reflection idea.  We also came up with it.  I've opted to go with a different approach though - of creating a request wrapper in a filter that supports replaying the inputstream.  I've then overridden the getParameter*() methods to read from a map that's been created by parsing the inputstream/payload.