# java.io.IOException: Stream closed - on Tomcat 8 - JavaMelody - JAX WS

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws, java-melody

I have upgraded my Tomcat from Version 7 to Version 8.0.30. Everything works fine until a WebService method is called, which should return a result.

[Edit: 25.01.2016] It seems that the response is empty, not even a root tag can be found.

When I switch back to Tomcat 7 everything works just fine.
I don't know where to look for the ideas. Can you help me with my Problem?

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Dynamic JAXWS Servlet] in 
context   with path [/edmwas] threw exception
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:446)
at net.bull.javamelody.PayloadNameRequestWrapper.resetBufferedInputStream(PayloadNameRequestWrapper.java:139)
at net.bull.javamelody.PayloadNameRequestWrapper.initialize(PayloadNameRequestWrapper.java:118)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.createRequestWrapper(MonitoringFilter.java:278)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:185)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:850)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:664)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's an extract from the javamelody PayloadNameRequestWrapper

```
protected void initialize() throws IOException {
    //name on a best-effort basis
    name = null;
    requestType = null;

    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest();
    final String contentType = request.getContentType();
    if (contentType == null) {
        //don't know how to handle this content type
        return;
    }

    if (!"POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        //no payload
        return;
    }

    //Try look for name in payload on a best-effort basis...
    try {
        if (contentType.startsWith("text/x-gwt-rpc")) {
            //parse GWT-RPC method name
            name = parseGwtRpcMethodName(getBufferedInputStream(), getCharacterEncoding());
            requestType = "GWT-RPC";
        } else if (contentType.startsWith("application/soap+xml") //SOAP 1.2
                || contentType.startsWith("text/xml") //SOAP 1.1
                && request.getHeader("SOAPAction") != null) {
            //parse SOAP method name
            name = parseSoapMethodName(getBufferedInputStream(), getCharacterEncoding());
            requestType = "SOAP";
        } else {
            //don't know how to name this request based on payload
            //(don't parse if text/xml for XML-RPC, because it is obsolete)
            name = null;
            requestType = null;
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("Error trying to parse payload content for request name", e);

        //best-effort - couldn't figure it out
        name = null;
        requestType = null;
    } finally {
        //reset stream so application is unaffected
        resetBufferedInputStream();
    }
}

protected BufferedInputStream getBufferedInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (bufferedInputStream == null) {
        //workaround Tomcat issue with form POSTs
        //see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18489399/read-httpservletrequests-post-body-and-then-call-getparameter-in-tomcat
        final ServletRequest request = getRequest();
        request.getParameterMap();

        //buffer the payload so we can inspect it
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream());
        // and mark to allow the stream to be reset
        bufferedInputStream.mark(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    return bufferedInputStream;
}


protected void resetBufferedInputStream() throws IOException {
    if (bufferedInputStream != null) {
        bufferedInputStream.reset(); // Exception happens here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think can be useful that you post the method that fires the exception

Comment: I added some lines of javamelody - PayloadNameRequestWrapper.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem is related to AJP Connectors and does not appear in every tomcat version. A bugreport already exists:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58481

In the bug report you can find a post where it says that

- Tomcat 7 should work till version 7.0.59. The Error appears in
  Version 7.0.61
- Tomcat 8 should work till version 8.0.20. The Error appears in
  Version 8.0.21